# Reads the file, but only inserts the last string in the file

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm reading from 3 files and merging them into one array called mergedfile but when I try to print the array it only prints out the last word in the first one. not sure if I read the files incorrectly or place the strings into the array wrong if anyone knows what could be the issue I would appreciate it. thanks.
the american files contain string that i need to sort alphabetically, and insert into word.txt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main()
{

    //open three files for merging
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("american0.txt","r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("american1.txt","r");
    FILE *fp3 = fopen("american2.txt","r");



    //open file to store the result
    FILE *fpm = fopen("words.txt", "w");



    //creating an array to save the files data
    char temp[50];
    char *(*mergedFile);
    //creating variables for while and if loops
    int i =0, j=0;
    int count=0;
    char *p;
    int q=0;
    int z = 0;



    //checking to make sure files are being read

    if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open one or all of the files.\n");
        printf("Exiting program!");
        exit(0);
    }




    //reading the data from files

    while (fgets(temp, 50 ,fp1) != NULL)
    {
        count++;
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    while (fgets(temp, 50 ,fp2) != NULL)
    {

        count++;
    }
    fclose(fp2);
    while (fgets(temp, 50 ,fp3) != NULL)
    {

        count++;
    }
    fclose(fp3);




    //inserting data into the array
    mergedFile = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) *count);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
        mergedFile[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);

    }
    fp1 = fopen("american0.txt","r");
    fp2 = fopen("american1.txt","r");
    fp3 = fopen("american2.txt","r");

    if(fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not open one or all of the files.\n");
        printf("Exiting program!");
        exit(0);
    }
    i=0;

    while (fgets(temp, 50, fp1) != NULL)
    {
         mergedFile[i++]= temp;     
    }

    while (fgets(temp, 50, fp2) != NULL)
    {
         mergedFile[i++]= temp;     
    }

    while (fgets(temp, 50, fp3) != NULL)
    {
         mergedFile[i++]= temp;     
    }
    for(z = 0; z <count; z++)
    printf("%s", mergedFile[z]);




    /*
    //sorting the array alphabetically
    for(i=1; i<count; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<count;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(mergedFile[j-1], mergedFile[j]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, mergedFile[j-1]);
                strcpy(mergedFile[j-1], mergedFile[j]);
                strcpy(mergedFile[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    */

    //next goal is to print the array to file word.txt



    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    //fclose(fpm);


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you do `fgets`, it overwrites `temp`.

Also, all entries in `mergedFile` are given the [same] pointer value to `temp`.

Thus, all entries will end up with the value of the *last* line of the third file.

You need to save a separate copy for each line. So, change all:

```
mergedFile[i++]= temp;
```

Into:

```
mergedFile[i++]= strdup(temp);
```